# PDO not being able to return the last_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-administration

```
   <?php
    session_start();


            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
            $categorynumber=0;
            $categorynumber = create_category($userid);
            //keep the category number for future reference
            if($categorynumber > 0){
                $_SESSION['categorynumber'] = $categorynumber;
            }

            echo $categorynumber;



    ?>
```

echo $categorynumber prints 0

```
    function create_category($userid)
{

    // connect to database with PDO
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    // insert category and get the category_id
    $categorynumber = 0;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (userid, name) VALUES (:userid, :name);SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', 'test7', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $result = array();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            array_push($result, $row);
        }

        if (isset($result[0][0]))
        $categorynumber = $result[0][0];

    }   

    // close database and return null 
    $dbh = null;
    return $categorynumber;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, so that I cannot retrieve the last id of the created entry? How can I return the last_insert_id(); and assign it to the $_SESSION['categorynumber']??

Comment: Try looking at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Also, does PDO even support multi query statements?

Comment: PDO should be able to handle multiple query statements. Its should only be an API for interactiing with the database. The concrete SQL should remain the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to achieve what I wanted with the following line:

```
$categorynumber = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

full example:

```
    function create_category($userid)
{

    // connect to database with PDO
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    // insert category and get the category_id
    $categorynumber = 0;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO categories (userid, name) VALUES (:userid, :name);");
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':name', 'test7', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $categorynumber = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    // close database and return null 
    $dbh = null;
    return $categorynumber;
}
```

Comment: anyone have any ideas how to adjust it to the race conditions? Does it need to be or PDO takes care of it?